# How to include bash command line arguments in an echo statement

Tags: bash, escaping

I'm writing a script that asks the user for several options and then, via a series of echo statements, creates and writes to a separate script file.  That script will also be dependent on at least one command line argument when executed.

Given the original statement

```
if [ "` echo $1 | egrep ^[[:digit:]]+$`" = "" ]
```

that determines if the first argument (`$1`) is an integer, how can I include that in the echo statement to be written to the new file while maintaining the command line argument access?

I tried to escape the double quotes and dollar signs like

```
echo "if [ \"` echo \$1 | egrep ^[[:digit:]]+\$`\" = \"\" ]" >> generatePanos
```

but that just resulted in

```
if [ "" = "" ]
```

However, `echo "\$1"` results in `$1` being printed in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what you mean, but here are two things you can try:

If you're trying to print the entire line as-is (including the `$1`), use single-quotes to tell `echo` to not interpret anything:

```
$ echo 'if [ "` echo $1 | egrep ^[[:digit:]]+$`" = "" ]'
if [ "` echo $1 | egrep ^[[:digit:]]+$`" = "" ]
```

If you're trying to print the entire line but substitute in the current value for `$1`:

```
$ echo "if [ \"\` echo $1 | egrep ^[[:digit:]]+\$\`\" = \"\" ]"
if [ "` echo <<some value>> | egrep ^[[:digit:]]+$`" = "" ]
```

If you're trying to substitute the entire portion of the command that's in backticks (evaluated using the current value of `$1`), it's probably best to use an intermediate variable:

```
temp=$(echo $1 | egrep ^[[:digit:]]+$)
echo "if [ \"$temp\" = \"\" ]"
```

Comment: You nailed it with the first option.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, recall that you can test for an empty string with `if [ -z <<something>> ]`, which involves fewer quotes to escape.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bash, you can use bash's builtin regex:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then 
   ...
fi
```

Even without bash's builtin regex, there is no need for the test command ( [ ), or `echo`:

```
if grep -q -E '^[[:digit:]]+$' <<< "$1"; then
   ...
fi
```

If this must also work on shells other than bash, then you can keep the `echo`:

```
if echo "$1" | grep -q -E '^[[:digit:]]+$'; then
   ...
fi
```

The last two work because `if` tests the exit status of a command. The `grep` command returns non-zero if a match is not found.

Answer (score 0):

put a back slash before every offending character:  echo if [ \"` echo $1 \| egrep ^[[:digit:]]+$`\" = \"\" ]

Answer (score -1):

echo "\$1" should do exactly what you said it did.
 
To echo the CONTENTS of '1' then echo $1 (without the backslash).

 When using variables in bash scripts, it's often good practice to double quote them (echo "$1", func_name "$1", etc) or to escape them ( echo "${1}" ).

As to the first part, are you wanting to echo the entire 'if' statement to the file? That's what it looks like. If not, then you should do this:

```
if [ conditions ]; then echo "$1" >> $filename
```

Comment: The test (alias [) command is not part of `if` syntax and not required.